# Треугольник на карточке товара с фоном

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Нужно сверстать вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Треугольник справа должен быть тоже с фоном как часть блока с фотографией. Таких карточек на странице должно быть много. Как такое сверстать ?

Comment: Я так подозреваю, что это скорее не фон, а продолжение фотографии. Значит можно просто поверх блока с фотографией наложить еще один блок с впуклым вырезом стрелочки. Профит!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно с помощью `clip-path`, но не совсем кросбраузерно ( уголок можно будет поменять )

Вот тут [онлайн генератор](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)

```css
div {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 90% 0, 90% 34%, 100% 50%, 91% 68%, 90% 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 90% 0, 90% 34%, 100% 50%, 91% 68%, 90% 100%, 0 100%);
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pJSdihKG65VhLXr1bhOl6qkNvch39AaUnwVPuUP3TPQPr4pIDIomz1JqwlKsLvNbwoYY=w300);
  background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Хорошее решение. Единственное что не работает в IE и Edge.

Answer (score 2):

Для кроссбраузерности можно заморочится и сделать так:

```css
#defs{
  width:1px;
  height:1px;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
}
.image{
  width:330px;
  height:300px;
}
```

```html
<!--определяем фигуру для обрезки-->
<svg id="defs">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="my-clip">
      <path d="M0,0 h300 v130 l30,20 -30,20 v130 h-300 z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
<!--Сами картинки-->
<svg viewBox="0 0 330 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" class="image">
  <image x="0" y="0" width="330" height="300" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" xlink:href="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pJSdihKG65VhLXr1bhOl6qkNvch39AaUnwVPuUP3TPQPr4pIDIomz1JqwlKsLvNbwoYY=w300" clip-path="url(#my-clip)"/>
</svg>
<svg viewBox="0 0 330 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" class="image">
  <image x="0" y="0" width="330" height="300" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" xlink:href="https://seguronosabias.files.wordpress.com/2013/09/bliss-4.png" clip-path="url(#my-clip)"/>
</svg>
<svg viewBox="0 0 330 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" class="image">
  <image x="0" y="0" width="330" height="300" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" xlink:href="https://defendingrussia.ru/upload/images/ckeditor5/4%20-%20Copy%201.jpg" clip-path="url(#my-clip)"/>
</svg>
```